# How to read only part of a line on a big file?

Tags: c#, file, pointers, stream

I have a 30GB log file to read and process,
In the first part I need to find a range of dates (which I get from the end-user) and then print them all.

So for the first part is it possible to read only the date on each line (which are the first 20 chars) and than moving to the beginning of the next line, instead of reading the whole line?

**C# coding**

Comment: One way or another, you're going to have to go through the entire line to get to the next one. It's just how text files are read.

Comment: Yeah so a text file is just a bunch of character bytes in a file.. It does not contain a dictionary of where all the line endings are. You will need to read every line to get the ending to get the start to get the range....

Comment: What about initialize the file pointer to the middle of the file and then using binary search with that pointer to find the wanted dates? Am I still going to move on them all?

Comment: Sure, go nuts...

Comment: _" then using binary search with that pointer to find the wanted dates"_ - OK, are all the lines a fixed length?

Comment: I am guessing the op means, bisecting the file like a binary search algorithm and finding the next end of line from that offset. i like the idea. Though it will take some mucking around. Orrrrr, you could just use a better logging framework that naturally stores structured logs in a db and indexes them.... there are many

Comment: No, it's not fixed..

Comment: No need for it to be fixed length, it just means that it won't be perfectly balanced "tree". Considering a normal log it will probably be close enough. You will have to step from the seek position until you find a new line though since you likely end up in the middle of a line. Sounds like a fun little project to test out :)

Comment: I was just thinking it could be difficult to find the right entries through such a technique if some rows were disproportionately longer than others. I'm sure it's possible with enough effort and testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text files are not special, they don't have anything like indexes to speed things up.  You WILL need to read all 30GB.   TBH 30GB isn't that much these days.  I've worked on systems that generate that much logging each DAY.   There are $$$ tools out there to help, if you regularly need to look at this much text, and they WILL pre-index the data, but if this is a one-off then something like:

```
while(!stream.EndOfStream)
{
     var line = stream.ReadLine();
     var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(line.SubString(20));
     if(dateTime >= start && <=end)
     { do something }
}
```

Comment: Its worth noting for modern SSDs, you can use a fairly large buffer size to increase the performance dramatically on the file stream, also setting the the sequential flag will also give a small gain as well